# how to insert same data in different table based on checkbox ? mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I want to insert data in multiple table

I have two tables >  recharge, due_user

**recharge table has**

```
>> ID - MOBno-  AMount - Network
```

**due_user has**

```
>> ID - userID - MOBno - Amount - NETWORK
```

in my form I have checkbox which will ask userID only if I click checkbox.

now insertion of data procedure would be .

*if unchecked*

```
 data > ID - mobno - Amount- Network
```

will be inserted in Recharging table
*if checked*

```
 data > ID-  userID -  mobile - amount - Network
```

will go both table Recharge and Due_user table but user id will we goes into only due usertable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your checkbox looks like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="isUserId" />
```

Then in php

```
<?php
    //here goes your recharge table insert
    if(isset($_POST['isUserId'])){
        //and here due user table insert
    }
?>
```

Comment: i want to insert data in both tabe .. in recharge list without userid and in due user list with user id